# Laravel is reseting my database even without RefreshDatabase trait

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I have a test class, and this child test class, within its `setUp` method, makes the call to the parent class in the `parent::setUp` method.

We have, within the `setUp` (parent) method, calling some sequences, namely:

- https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php
- `$this->refreshApplication();`
- `$this->setUpTraits();`
- ...

If we look deeper inside the `setUpTraits` method, we can notice the following conditional:

```
protected function setUpTraits()
{
        $uses = array_flip(class_uses_recursive(static::class));

        if (isset($uses[RefreshDatabase::class])) {
            $this->refreshDatabase();
        }
}
```

That is, the code above tells me that if my current test class `static::class`, if it has a trait called `RefreshDatabase`, then I will be giving carte blanche to reset my database, correct?

However, here comes the problem.

I'm doing an integration test, that is, I'm using the class as base `ExampleTest` in the x10 version of Laravel:

- https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/10.x/tests/Feature/ExampleTest.php

At no time am I making use of the trait, nor are the classes that I make the extension:

- https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/10.x/tests/TestCase.php

Why on earth does my application reset my database every time I run my unit tests?

Every time my `APP_ENV` is set to `testing`, does Laravel automatically understand that it is authorized to do this implicitly?

How do I manually ignore this `refreshDatabase` trait and have the code understand that I don't want to deal with it?

According to the Laravel documentation, he mentions at one point about creating the database, running the migrations and etc... does he always do this by himself?

- https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/testing#parallel-testing-and-databases

Can I run the tests on a different bank without necessarily needing to run the migrations?

Comment: Does maybe your tests/TestCase.php file include the `RefreshDatabse` trait?

Comment: If you are not using `RefreshDatabse` anywhere in any test file, then you have something somewhere doing the call or wiping the database itself. What command are you executing to run the test (literal command with arguments and everything)?

Comment: i'm a donkey.
I looked in all possible files, even the laravel core I looked.
And I didn't have the ability to look at my main test class. Really, refreshDatabase was being used there and it passed because of my despair. Thank you guys.